# Create a Publisher that notifies subscribers one by one, waiting for eachother

Tags: swift, combine

I have this publisher and subscribers (example code):

```
import Combine

let publisher = PassthroughSubject<ComplexStructOrClass, Never>()
let sub1 = publisher.sink { (someString) in
    // Async work...
}

let sub2 = publisher.sink { (someString) in
    // Async work, but it has to wait until sub1 has finished his work
}
```

So the `publisher` constant has 2 subscribers. When I use the method `send` on the `publisher` constant, it should send the value first to `sub1` and **after** `sub1` finished processing (with a callback or something like that), `publisher` should and notify `sub2`.

So in the comments its stated that Combine is made for this. What publisher do I need to use? A PassthroughSubject may be the wrong decision.

**Usecase**

I need to publish values throughout the lifetime of my app to a dynamic number of subscribers, for a few different publishers (I hope I can make a protocol). So a subscriber can be added and removed from a publisher at any given time. A subscriber look as follows:

- It has a `NSPersistentContainer`
- A callback should be made by the publisher when a new value has arrived. That process looks like:

  1. the publisher will create a backgroundContext of the container of the subscriber, because it knows a subscriber has a container
  2. the publisher sends the context along with the new published value to the subscriber
  3. the publisher waits until it receives a callback of the subscriber. The subscriber shouldn't save the context, but the publisher must hold a reference to the context. The subscriber gives a callback of an enum, which has a ok case and some error cases.
  4. When a subscriber gives a callback with an error enum case, the publisher must rollback the contexts it created for each subscriber.
  5. When a subscriber gives a callback with the ok case, the publisher repeats step 1 till 5 for every subscriber
  6. This step will only be reached when no subscriber gave a error enum case or there are no subscribers. The publisher will save all the contexts created by the subscribers.

**Current code, no Combine**
This is some code without using `Combine`:

```
// My publisher
protocol NotiPublisher {

    // Type of message to send
    associatedtype Notification

    // List of subscribers for this publisher
    static var listeners: Set<AnyNotiPublisher<Notification>> { get set }
}

// My subscriber
protocol NotificationListener: Hashable {
    associatedtype NotificationType

    var container: NSPersistentContainer { get }
    // Identifier used to find this subscriber in the list of 'listeners' in the publisher
    var identifier: Int32 { get }
    var notify: ((_ notification: NotificationType, _ context: NSManagedObjectContext, @escaping CompletionHandlerAck) -> ()) { get }
}

// Type erased version of the NotificationListener and some convience methods here, can add them if desired

// In a extension of NotiPublisher, this method is here
static func notify(queue: DispatchQueue, notification: Notification, completionHander: @escaping CompletionHandlerAck) throws {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var completionBlocks = [SomeCompletionHandler]()
    var contexts = [NSManagedObjectContext]()
    var didLoop = false

    for listener in listeners {
        if didLoop {
            dispatchGroup.wait()
        } else {
            didLoop = true
        }

        dispatchGroup.enter()

        listener.container.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
            contexts.append(context)

            listener.notify(notification, context, { (completion) in                    
                completionBlocks.append(completion)

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: queue) {
        let err = completion.first(where: { element in
            // Check if an error has occured
        })

        if err == nil {
            for context in contexts {
                context.performAndWait {
                    try! context.save()
                }
            }
        }

        completionHander(err ?? .ok(true))
    }
}
```

This is pretty complex code, I am wondering if I can make use of the power of Combine to make this code more readable.

Comment: Not with `sink`, though. Sink is "drop me out of combine land and just call these call backs". There's no chaining after that. You probably want to use some variant of `map`. Your `publisher` emits X objects, which get piped into the first closure, which gets mapped to Y objects, which get piped to the second closure to produce your resulting Z objects.

Comment: @Alexander The subscribers are dynamic (can be added and removed at any time). It should be guaranteed that the subscribers that are added the last, are notified as last (when all the other subscribers are done working). When using the map function, a new publisher will be returned right? How can I make sure I keep sending values to the newest publisher? I don't see how map can be used to accomplish this task

Comment: @J.Doe "It should be guaranteed that the subscribers that are added the last, are notified as last" I'm not sure if that's a guarantee that reactive frameworks make. I know that for one subscription, one event won't be emitted until the reaction to the previous is complete. I don't think that applies across multiple subscriptions, though. `When using the map function, a new publisher will be returned right?` Yes, but I'm not sure what your point is. `How can I make sure I keep sending values to the newest publisher?` I don't understand this question.

Comment: If a new publisher is returned for each time I add/remove a subscriber, how do I know to what publisher I need to send my values to for the publisher to publish? Or create a variable and reassign it everytime a subscriber is changed?

Comment: I could be wrong, but to me it sounds like the problem you're describing is best suited for an operation queue. You would then need one subscriber to handle incoming events, an array of listeners, and some sort of asynchronous operation that represents each listener processing the latest event. Whenever an event comes in, the manager would create an operation for each listener, and add it to the queue. I don't think it'd take all that much to adapt your current code to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following to chain async operations from a publisher using flatMap that allows you to return another publisher. I'm not a fan, and it might not meet your need to dynamically change the subs, but it might help someone:

```
let somePublisher = Just(12)

let anyCancellable = somePublisher.flatMap{ num in
    //We can return a publisher from flatMap, so lets return a Future one because we want to do some async work
    return Future<Int,Never>({ promise  in

        //do an async thing using dispatch
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: {
            print("flat map finished processing the number \(num)")

            //now just pass on the value
            promise(.success(num))
        })
    })
}.flatMap{ num in
    //We can return a publisher from flatMap, so lets return a Future one because we want to do some async work
    return Future<Int,Never>({ promise  in

        //do an async thing using dispatch
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: {
            print("second flat map finished processing the number \(num)")

            //now just pass on the value
            promise(.success(num))
        })
    })
}.sink { num in
    print("This sink runs after the async work in the flatMap/Future publishers")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use serial `OperationQueue` to `receive` values. Seems like it will wait until `sink` completes before call another.

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

publisher
    .receive(on: queue)
    .sink { _ in }
```